# checking the value present in table in jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I will obtain the input value from the user and need to insert into `sqlite` table in phonegap

But before inserting the value i need to check whether the value is already present in table of phonegap.

How can i do this in phonegap?.

Comment: what have you tried to this point. do you have anything we can work off of? kinda flying blind here. with that said its not hard to iterate over the table with jquery but need something to go off of.

Comment: i tried querying like this `tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table', [], querySuccess, errorCB);` and compare the value but i was not successfull..

Comment: You wanna insert into sqlite. users here will get the idea that you wanna insert data into `<table></table>` unless you explicitly mention :)

Comment: @Mayu sorry . i will edit it now.